# My div content gets overlapped by the next div when i switch to small devices

Tags: html, css, overlap, bootstrap-5, overlapping

I'm using bootstrap and when I'm switching to small devices my content gets overlapped by the next div. I tried to change everything and put margin on my bottom of my div but nothing seems to work. I'm missing something. I'm not sure if it something with the relative potitions I tried to add so I can add my svgs in the bottom of each div.

The HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid  vh-100 " id="projects">
  <!-- <div class="container d-flex h-100 " id="pwrap"> -->
    <div class="row align-items-center mx-auto " id="cards">
      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 ">
        <div class="card" >
          <img src="pics/project1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class=" col-sm-6 col-lg-4  ">
        <div class="card" >
          <img src="pics/project1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4  ">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="pics/project1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <svg class="botp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#FFB9B9" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,192L48,165.3C96,139,192,85,288,96C384,107,480,181,576,218.7C672,256,768,256,864,245.3C960,235,1056,213,1152,218.7C1248,224,1344,256,1392,272L1440,288L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>
  <!-- </div> -->
</div>

<!-- /projects -->

<!-- contact -->

<div class="container-fluid  w-100 vh-100 my-auto  d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center " id="contact">
  <!--Section: Contact v.2-->

  <div id="border-shadow">

<div class="border border-success p-3" id="bordercustom">

    <section class="mb-4 " id="formcustom">

      <!--Section heading-->
      <h2 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-4">Contact Me</h2>

      <div class="row justify-content-center">

          <!--Grid column-->
          <div class="col-md-9 mb-md-0 mb-5">
              <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST">

                  <!--Grid row-->
                  <div class="row">

                      <!--Grid column-->
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="md-form mb-0">
                              <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
                              <label for="name" class="">Your name</label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--Grid column-->

                      <!--Grid column-->
                      <div class="col-md-6">
                          <div class="md-form mb-0">
                              <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                              <label for="email" class="">Your email</label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!--Grid column-->

                  </div>
                  <!--Grid row-->

                  <!--Grid row-->
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-12">
                          <div class="md-form mb-0">
                              <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
                              <label for="subject" class="">Subject</label>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--Grid row-->

                  <!--Grid row-->
                  <div class="row">

                      <!--Grid column-->
                      <div class="col-md-12">

                          <div class="md-form">
                              <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="2" class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
                              <label for="message">Your message</label>
                          </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <!--Grid row-->

              </form>

              <div class="text-center text-md-left d-flex justify-content-center">
                <a class="button mt-3" onclick="validateForm();">
    <span class="default">Send</span>
    <span class="success">Sent</span>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</a>

              </div>
              <div class="status"></div>
          </div>
          <!--Grid column-->



        </div>
      </div>

  </section>
  <!--Section: Contact v.2-->

</div>
<svg class="botc"xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320"><path fill="#363C62" fill-opacity="1" d="M0,288L60,272C120,256,240,224,360,224C480,224,600,256,720,277.3C840,299,960,309,1080,293.3C1200,277,1320,235,1380,213.3L1440,192L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z"></path></svg>
</div>


<!-- /contact -->
```

and my css

```
#home,
#about,
#projects,
#contact{
  position: relative;
}

 #projects .botp{
   z-index: 1;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left:0;
 }
 #cards{
   z-index: 2;
 }
 #contact .botc{
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 0;
   left:0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so i randomly fixed it just by adding this code on css

```
.card-img-top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 15vw;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? I've run your code, and it's not overlapping (*I'm using Opera/Google Chrome*).

Also, you can add **`height: auto`** to the divisions `div`, it may help :)

### EDIT:

(*I finally got what you mean*)

Just play with the `z-index`. Here is the code:

**CSS**

```
#home,
#about,
#projects,
#contact {
  position: relative;
}

 #projects .botp {
   z-index: 1;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   position: absolute;
 }

 #contact {
     z-index: 10;
 }

 #projects {
     z-index: 10;
 }

.botc{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1;
   left: 0;
   bottom: 200px;
 }

 #card-text {
     z-index: 10000;
 }

.botp {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 500px;
     z-index: 1;
 }

 .col-md-6 {
     z-index: 10;
 }
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid  vh-100 " id="projects">
        <!-- <div class="container d-flex h-100 " id="pwrap"> -->
        <div class="row align-items-center mx-auto " id="cards">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 ">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="pics/project1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="pics/project1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
                <div class="card">
                    <img src="pics/project1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title" style="z-index: 10;">Card title</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the card's content.</p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <svg class="botp" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path fill="#FFB9B9" fill-opacity="1"
            d="M0,192L48,165.3C96,139,192,85,288,96C384,107,480,181,576,218.7C672,256,768,256,864,245.3C960,235,1056,213,1152,218.7C1248,224,1344,256,1392,272L1440,288L1440,320L1392,320C1344,320,1248,320,1152,320C1056,320,960,320,864,320C768,320,672,320,576,320C480,320,384,320,288,320C192,320,96,320,48,320L0,320Z">
        </path>
    </svg>
        <!-- </div> -->
    

    <!-- /projects -->

    <!-- contact -->

    <div class="container-fluid  w-100 vh-100 my-auto  d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center " id="contact">
        <!--Section: Contact v.2-->

        <div id="border-shadow">

            <div class="border border-success p-3" id="bordercustom">

                <section class="mb-4 " id="formcustom">

                    <!--Section heading-->
                    <h2 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-4">Contact Me</h2>

                    <div class="row justify-content-center">

                        <!--Grid column-->
                        <div class="col-md-9 mb-md-0 mb-5">
                            <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php" method="POST">

                                <!--Grid row-->
                                <div class="row">

                                    <!--Grid column-->
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
                                            <label for="name" class="">Your name</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Grid column-->

                                    <!--Grid column-->
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                                            <label for="email" class="">Your email</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!--Grid column-->

                                </div>
                                <!--Grid row-->

                                <!--Grid row-->
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                            <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control">
                                            <label for="subject" class="">Subject</label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--Grid row-->

                                <!--Grid row-->
                                <div class="row">

                                    <!--Grid column-->
                                    <div class="col-md-12">

                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <textarea type="text" id="message" name="message" rows="2"
                                                class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
                                            <label for="message">Your message</label>
                                        </div>

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--Grid row-->

                            </form>

                            <div class="text-center text-md-left d-flex justify-content-center">
                                <a class="button mt-3" onclick="validateForm();">
                                    <span class="default">Send</span>
                                    <span class="success">Sent</span>
                                    <div class="left"></div>
                                    <div class="right"></div>
                                </a>

                            </div>
                            <div class="status"></div>
                        </div>
                        <!--Grid column-->



                    </div>
            </div>

            </section>
            <!--Section: Contact v.2-->

        </div>
        
    </div>


    <!-- /contact -->
    <svg class="botc" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1440 320">
        <path fill="#363C62" fill-opacity="1"
            d="M0,288L60,272C120,256,240,224,360,224C480,224,600,256,720,277.3C840,299,960,309,1080,293.3C1200,277,1320,235,1380,213.3L1440,192L1440,320L1380,320C1320,320,1200,320,1080,320C960,320,840,320,720,320C600,320,480,320,360,320C240,320,120,320,60,320L0,320Z">
        </path>
    </svg>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: hey, thank you for helping! But unfortunately, it doesn't work. My problem is that my #projects div doesnt expand to cover the my content and it ends up overlapped. I also trried adding heigh:auto .